# mysqli module not working

Tags: php, mysqli

i'm trying to use mysqli module for PHP5 and it doesn't work. The module is activated in php.ini. What could be the problem?

```
<?php
require_once("class/guestbook.php");

$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$db   = "guestbook";

//Connect
$c = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);

//Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connection failed! %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
}


//Return the name of current database
if($result = $c->query("SELECT_DATABASE();")) {
    $row = $result->fetch_row();
    printf("Default database is %s.\n", $row[0]);
    $result->close();
}

//Close connection
$c->close();


?>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Could you tell us the error message you have received? Turn on all errors in php.ini so you get more detailed error and warning messages.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: I don't see a `SELECT_DATABASE()` function. Do you mean to do [`SELECT DATABASE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_database)?

Comment: any errors or warnings?

Comment: I have error_reporting = E_ALL and i receive no error messages (no notices, no warnings, no fatal error). The problem is that $result=$c->query ("SELECT_DATABASE();") is false, i don't understand why, the syntax looks ok.

Comment: @Sean Thank you, it was SELECT DATABASE() not SELECT_DATABASE().

Answer (score 1):

The only thing wrong with your neat code, most probably, is your query itself.

```
SELECT_DATABASE(); // returns an error for obvious reasons
```

Means nothing to mysql. This does

```
SELECT DATABASE();
```

You don't see the error message because you don't check for errors on query execution. You are only looking for connection errors. Try an `else{}` block for `$c->query` and print the error message to see it.